# Mysql: query is not executing

Tags: php, mysql, magento

The below query is not executing .. Please let me know the problem..

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `catalog_category_entity_varchar` (
  `value_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entity_type_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `attribute_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`value_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IDX_BASE` (`entity_type_id`,`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `FK_ATTRIBUTE_VARCHAR_ENTITY` (`entity_id`),
  KEY `FK_CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE` (`attribute_id`),
  KEY `FK_CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_VARCHAR_STORE` (`store_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1122 ;
```

This table belongs to the Magento Project..

Comment: the syntax is ok, u have permission to create ?

Comment: yes i have permission to create. There is no permission problem..

Comment: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USING BTREE,
  KEY `FK_ATTRIBUTE_VARCHAR_ENTITY` (`entity_id`),
  KEY `FK_CATA' at line 9 `  This is the error is showing when i try execute in phpmyadmin.

Comment: In the above query what this line is meant?? Is referring to any other table??  `KEY 'FK_CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_VARCHAR_ATTRIBUTE' ('attribute_id'),`

Comment: @Mayilarun:  it creates a key field based on the `attribute_id` to speed up queries.

Comment: Works for me (om MySQL 5.0 and 5.1). Try to remove 'USING BTREE' - it is default value.

Comment: The query is exactly of right syntax and i tried it on my localhost and it created the table with the specified indexes. Make you when you type u doesn't miss characters like , ` (u may be using ' instead of `)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mysql versions prior to 5.1 you have to use USING BTREE before parenthesis.
Try changing

```
UNIQUE KEY `IDX_BASE` (`entity_type_id`,`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`) USING BTREE
```

to

```
UNIQUE KEY `IDX_BASE` USING BTREE (`entity_type_id`,`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`)
```